# TCP/IP file transfer C++

Tags: c++, tcp, ip, tcpclient

I'm a beginner in programming in c++ with a bit of experience in java.
My goal is transfer files (in local host) between a server and a client (in two different folders).

I have found this code online that works well for me, it opens sockets and makes a connection between the server and the client and you can send a message typed in the terminal.

I have tried a lot of different codes on the INTERNET and either it doesn't compile or it isn't what I need.

Here is a code that I found that works to transmit a message.

server.cpp file

```
enter code here
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
 socklen_t clilen;
 char buffer[256];
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
 int n;
 if (argc < 2) {
     fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
     exit(1);
 }
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sockfd < 0) {
    error("ERROR opening socket");
exit(1);
    }
 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 portno = atoi(argv[1]);
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)             { 
error("ERROR on binding");
}
 listen(sockfd,1);
 clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
 newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
             (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
             &clilen);
 if (newsockfd < 0) 
      error("ERROR on accept");
 bzero(buffer,256);
 n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
 if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
 printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
 n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
 if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
 close(newsockfd);
 close(sockfd);
 return 0; 
 }
```

client.cpp file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd, portno, n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

char buffer[256];
if (argc < 3) {
   fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
   exit(0);
}
portno = atoi(argv[2]);
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
     server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR connecting");
printf("Please enter the message: ");
bzero(buffer,256);
fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);
close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with g++ in ubuntu.

I'd love if you could help me to at least be able to send a txt file from the client or download a file from the server, as soon as i try to add functionalities in this code nothing works anymore, maybe I'm starting with a bad example?

Comment: I'm confused - you said it works well for you... what's the question?  (and why is it important that you got your code off the INTERNET?)

Comment: This code is like a chat app. He wants to send files.

Comment: Maybe look at (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html). Disclaimer: haven't used it. But it's generally a good idea to look at Boost first, and only if it doesn't do all that one wants, other libraries.

Comment: Ok, so what change did you make, and what error did it cause?

Comment: By it works well I mean this code does what it needs to do, but I'm not able to make changes so i can transfer files.
I' take a look in boost then.thx.

Comment: I tried to make a menu with a switch case to let the client choose different options to do, send file, download a file, send a message, and show the servers files, like a index of what could the user download.
But I wasn't able to event make the client to send a message in the case, I found that c++ is pretty hard and it's hard to find answers on internet for such precise cases of mine

Answer (score 5):

you should try this example, it works good for me

receive:

```
size_t datasize;
FILE* fd = fopen(filename, "wb");
while (!received)
{
    datasize = recv(connection, text, sizeof(text), 0);
    fwrite(&text, 1, datasize, fd);
}
fclose(fd);
```

send:

```
FILE *fd = fopen(filename, "rb");
size_t rret, wret;
int bytes_read;
while (!feof(fd)) {
    if ((bytes_read = fread(&buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fd)) > 0)
        send(sock, buffer, bytes_read, 0);
    else
        break;
}
    fclose(fd);
```

Good luck:)